# Почему x = x++ не приводит к увеличению значения x в цикле?

Tags: java

```
int x = 0;
while (x < 3) {
    x = x++;
    System.out.print(x + " ");
}
```

Я понимаю, что если написано `y = x++`, то сначала `y` присваивается значение `х`, после чего `х` увеличивается на единицу. Почему этого не происходит с выражением `х = х++`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
x = x++;
```

эквивалентно

```
int tmp = x;
x++;
x = tmp;
```

Сначала присваивается старое значение, делается инкрементирование, присваивается старое значение - поэтому цикл бесконечный, `x = 0` всегда.

Comment: Такой порядок регламентируется, или это случайность? К примеру, возможна ли такая последовательность: сначала вычисляется часть выражения справа от знака присваивания (x до инкремента), затем происходит присваивание (x = x), после чего происходит инкремент (x =  x + 1).

Comment: @VladimirGamalian в Java и C# - регламентируется. В Си/С++ это была бы случайность.

Comment: @PavelMayorov ага, теперь картина ясно, спасибо!

Answer (score 14):

`x++` увеличивает `x` и возвращает старое значение (т.е. `0`). `x =` присваивает старое значение обратно. И `x` снова становится равным `0`. В следующей итерации все повторяется;

В итоге `x` всегда будет `0`

Посмотрите в отладчике.

Comment: Такой порядок регламентируется или это случайность? Может ли быть, что инкремент произойдет после присваивания?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian есть два вида подобных унарных операций: преинкремент (++x) и постинкремент (x++). Преинкремент - значение сначала увеличивается, а потом присваивается, постинкремент - происходит то, что описано в данном вопросе. То же самое и с декрементом.

Answer (score 5):

Если рассмотреть, байткод который генерируется из выражения :

```
int x = 0;
x = x++;
```

То получим следущее:

```
 0: iconst_0     // положить на стек 0
 1: istore_1     // сохранение значения в переменную 1
 2: iload_1      // положить на стек значение из переменной 1
 3: iinc  1, 1   // увеличение значения переменной с индексом 1 на 1
 6: istore_1     // сохранение значения 0 в переменную 1
 7: return
```

Что эквивалентно:

```
byte var10000 = x;
int x1 = x + 1;
x = var10000;
```

Comment: Может ли случится так, что сначала будет вычислено выражение после знака `=`, затем произойдет присваивание, и только после этого инкремент?

Comment: не совсем понял, выражение после = это что?

Comment: т.е. берем x, присваиваем его себе же, затем выполняется инкремент

Comment: x=(x=x)++ это не имеет смысла. а выражение x=x++ я расмотрел в ответе. порядок фиксированный, тут неожиданностей не может быть.

Answer (score -1):

Потому что у вас стоит постфиксный инкремент, то есть сначала присваивается, а потом инкрементируется. Чтобы работало нужно использовать префиксный инкремент `++x`

[погуглите](https://www.google.ru/?q=difference+between+postfix+and+prefix+java) про отличия постфиксного и префиксного инкремента/декремента.

Comment: Если сначала присваивается, затем инкрементируется, почему после инкремента возвращается к исходному значению?