# Возвращаются разные значения после инкремента

Tags: javascript, инкремент

Изучаю JS и не понятен такой момент:

```
var q = 3;
q++;
alert(q);    //4

var w = 3;
w = w++;
alert(w);    //3
```

Записи похожи, но результаты возвращаются разные. Можете объяснить почему так?

Comment: [Вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/608124/183458) написано как работает постфиксный инкремент в Java. В JavaScript он работает так же.

Comment: Исходя из объяснения, получается, что в выражении 
'w = w++' 
сначала идет присваивание потом инкремент. Возврат старого значение и цикл повторяется. НО каким образом сначала происходит присваивание а не инкремент, ведь приоритетность последнего гораздо выше?

Comment: Там три действия: сохранение старого значения `w`, затем инкремент, потом присваивание в `w` старого значения. Инкремент происходит **раньше**, чем присваивание, потому что приоритет у инкремента действительно выше. Постфиксный инкремент (`w++`) возвращает (а именно возвращённое значение потом и присваивается с помощью `=`) старое значение. Так заложено в языках программирования: `w++` возвращает старое значение, `++w` - новое (увеличенное на единицу).

Answer (score -1):

```
w = w++;
```

ты делаешь присвоение и потом делаешь alert присвоенного значения.

Comment: Вызов инкремента происходит

Comment: да, сорри, не так выразился, `var w = 3, c = 0; c = w++; alert( w );` вот так будет корректней.

Comment: Нет, то что вы написали в комментарии - некорректно. В этом случае `c` будет равно 3, а `w` - 4.

Comment: а что если написать w = ++w; вместо w = w++?

Comment: @MuzaffarRasulov тогда `w` будет равно 4, так как префиксный инкремент возвращает новое (увеличенное на единицу) значение.

Comment: да согласен, вы уже более расширенно ответили ТСу )