# Непонятно как работает counts[x]++

Tags: java, массивы

Как понять этот код `counts[x]++`?

Смотрела примеры, запускала код с отладчиком. Можно самый простой пример?

Comment: Значение по индексу `x` массива `counts` наращивается на единицу. Если, конечно, оно имеет числовой тип, иначе будет ошибка.

Comment: Тоже дошло, вернулась, чтобы написать, а мне уже ответили

Comment: @svil Вам "ответил" умник при помощи Chat GPT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Для начала разберёмся вообще, что делает это таинственное `++`.

Возьмём вот такой код:

```java
int number = 5;
number++;
System.out.println(number);
```

Вставим в метод `main()` и запустим. Получаем вывод:

```
6
```

То есть переменная увеличилась на один. Отсюда вывод:

```java
number++;
```

то же самое, что и

```java
number = number + 1;
```

**Обновление:** не совсем тоже самое, см [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/608124/532877). Но в данном конкретном случае разницы не будет. А чтобы разницы не было ни в каком случае, можно `number++` на `++numner` заменить.

#### Загадочное `counts[x]`

У нас же была другая запись:

```java
counts[x]++;
```

Раз мы уже знаем, что такое `++`, то осталось лишь понять что такое `counts[x]`.

Представим эту запись попроще: `counts[4]`. `counts` - это массив. А 4 - это индекс в массиве, порядковый номер элемента в массиве (**Первый индекс массива - ноль!!!**). Чтобы стало понятней, продемонстрирую на коде:

```java
int counts = new int[]{
                       4, //Это counts[0]
                       3, //Это counts[1]
                       9, //Это counts[2]
                       5, //Это counts[3]
                       7  //Это counts[4]
                      };

System.out.println(counts[4]); //Выведет 7, так как в counts[4] мы положили число 7
```

А `x` - это переменная (целочисленного типа). До этого мы обращались к индексу массива, записывая в квадратные скобки число (`counts[4]`). Но в квадратные скобки можно записать и целочисленную переменную.  Тогда из переменной будет взято число - оно и будет индексом массива, к которому мы обратимся:

```
int x = 4;
System.out.println(counts[x]); // 7
counts[x]++;
System.out.println(counts[x]); // а теперь 8
```

#### Подытожим

Запись `counts[x]++` означает, что мы обращаемся к массиву `counts`, берём элемент с индексом `x`, и увеличиваем этот элемент на единицу. Индекс `x` при этом не изменяется.

Comment: Подытожим: `и увеличиваем этот индекс на один`  Индекс - это как раз `x`. 
В предыдущей части тоже про индекс нехорошо. Я понимаю, что вы хотели попроще объяснить, но в понятиях возникла путаница

Comment: @MBo исправил путаницу.

Comment: Посмотрите, мои правки вроде не нарушают ваши замыслы, пример сделал более полноценным, и терминологию причесал немного.

Comment: _то же самое, что и

number = number + 1;_ - не то же самое, потому что возвращается предыдущее значение

Comment: @Grundy дописал про это. Спасибо за замечание!

Answer (score -5):

Выражение counts[x]++ увеличивает значение элемента массива counts, индекс которого равен x, на 1.

Пример использования: предположим, что у нас есть массив counts, который содержит количество разных цветов шариков в корзине, а также переменная x, которая хранит текущий выбранный цвет шарика. Чтобы увеличить счетчик выбранного цвета, мы можем использовать выражение counts[x]++:

```
//JS
let counts = [0, 0, 0, 0]; // массив для подсчета количества шариков разных цветов
let x = 2; // выбранный цвет - третий по порядку (индекс 2)
counts[x]++; // увеличиваем счетчик выбранного цвета на 1
console.log(counts); // [0, 0, 1, 0]
```

```
//Java
int[] counts = new int[4]; // массив для подсчета количества шариков разных цветов
int x = 2; // выбранный цвет - третий по порядку (индекс 2)
counts[x]++; // увеличиваем счетчик выбранного цвета на 1
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(counts)); // [0, 0, 1, 0]
```

В этом примере после выполнения counts[x]++ значение counts[2] увеличивается на 1, и теперь массив counts выглядит как [0, 0, 1, 0], что означает, что в корзине есть один шарик третьего цвета.

Comment: Несмотря на изменения в политике, [НЕ стоит генерировать ответы при помощи Chat GPT](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12247/)